# How to represent golang "any" type in protobuf language

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc-go, grpc-gateway

am using a protobuf definition file to create golang classes

file.proto

```
message my_message {
 <what type to use?> data = 1 [json_name = "data"]
}
```

generated.go

```
type MyMessage struct {
  data any
}
```

I have checked out  [Struct](https://protobuf.dev/reference/protobuf/google.protobuf/#struct) , [Value](https://protobuf.dev/reference/protobuf/google.protobuf/#value) and [Any](https://protobuf.dev/reference/protobuf/google.protobuf/#any), though none of them actually mark the type as “any” in generated classes.

The closes I get is `Value` type which can accomodate primitives as well as structs and lists.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware the Go code generator doesn't have any circumstances where `any`/`interface{}` will be used for a generated field.

`google.protobuf.Any` is likely what you want here, but the field in the generated code will of type [`anypb.Any`](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf-go/blob/master/types/known/anypb/any.pb.go#L214). If you absolutely require the `any` type be used, you'll unfortunately have to manually map to another struct.

Comment: Well I can see google.protobuf.Any gives you the advantage of referencing some other proto message type, but I don't see the need for it. I guess google.protobuf.Value would do ?

Comment: If you're only needing to hold primitive types, `google.protobuf.Struct`, `google.protobuf.ListValue`, `google.protobuf.NullValue`, then yes, `google.protobuf.Value` should be fine.